# Add new value in partition (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

I have changeset like this:

```
<sql>
create table ${prefix}_partition_table partition of ${prefix}_main_table for values in (1, 3, 5, 7, 15);
</sql>
```

How I can add new value in values list (17 for example)? I can't find an example anywhere. Only examples with the creation of a new partition and merging?

I tried writing something like "alter table 'name' add partition('partition name' values(17))"; But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to detach the table from the partition using [ALTER TABLE ... DETACH-PARTITION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-DETACH-PARTITION) and then attach it with the updated list of values using [ALTER TABLE ... ATTACH-PARTITION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-ATTACH-PARTITION).

Reads and writes during this operation are probably a bad idea and foreign keys might pose a challenge, too.